# Painting facia boards

Tags: paint, repainting

Any tips on painting facis boards that are in full sun for the majority of the day? I have facia boards that need to be painted about every 5 yrs or so due to peeling. Do i need to prep better? I usually use latex paint.

Comment: 5 years is a short life on paint if it is quality paint placed on a properly prepared surface. I have used latex for years on my last home the paint still looks good after close to 15 years all the white trim and medium to light blue,  much of the home is in full sun ok in Oregon but I have seen others paint there homes 2 times since then and my opinion was they used cheap paint but I know my neighbor did prep well because I helped him.

Comment: From what i understand, its not cheap paint(km) i usually remove all loose chips. Very light sanding.  Clean off with water hose,  let dry  then prime and paint. Any tips on prepping?

Comment: are you using cheap primer? Does the paint have a primer base already in it? Is there an oil based paint already on the surface? Any idea what kind of wood the facia is?

Comment: No, not cheap primer(k.moore)  i have always use a separate primer and paint, not sure  of the type of wood. I've been in the house 20yrs, house is about 55yrs old. And i have never used oil base paint.

Comment: With paint, you want the wood to be dry and warm, but not hot.  How long do you let the wood dry after hosing it off?  How hot is it outside when you do your painting, typically?  Are you using exterior-grade paint?

Comment: I use a steam/ hot pressure washer then scrape any loose material and prime/ fill if large chips and paint. If two hot the paint won't stick well, do the full sun side before it gets hot.

Comment: @chris m. I usually will hose off the facia in the morning and will prim tje next day. Cant remember how hot it was last time . Im guessing around 65-75 Fahrenheit.  Yes using exterior paint.